# Commerce add product attribute without adding new product variations

Tags: 7, commerce

I have found this Commerce manual: [Product Attributes & Variations](https://drupalcommerce.org/user-guide/product-attributes-variations), which explains the differences and connections between fields, attributes and variations, where in the end they assign a different product to each product display.

The situation I am in is as follows. Let's say I sell lunchboxes. The same model is available in 5 colors and the lid is always white. But now I want to add an option to the shop where people can order a lid in the same color as the lunchbox. My SKU's are as follows:

- lunchbox_red
- lunchbox_blue
- lunchbox_...

I was hoping this could become a simple product attribute (a checkbox?), but it seems I will have to add a second version of my 5 products with the extra costs of the lid:

- lunchbox_red
- lunchbox_red_lid_red
- lunchbox_blue
- lunchbox_blue_lid_blue
- lunchbox_...

I initially wanted to let people choose the color of the lid, but that would require me to maintain 25 different products for each box-lid combination!?

- lunchbox_red
- lunchbox_red_lid_red
- lunchbox_red_lid_blue
- lunchbox_red_lid_...
- lunchbox_blue
- lunchbox_blue_lid_red
- lunchbox_blue_lid_blue
- lunchbox_...

Since I don't really care about the photo (I would definitely need a product for each lid combination in that case), I was hoping for a smarter way to implement this.

Can I add a general attribute (with added costs) to all product variations without adding all the products? The price for the coloring of the lid will be a fixed price, not depending on the color used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears I have been looking for [Commerce Pricing Attributes](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_pricing_attributes). There is one SKU with a base price and I can manage the attributes and add a price modifier for each of them.

This screenshot from the module page explains it all:

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

You could bundle your products with [commerce_product_bundle](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_product_bundle).

> So you only have the lunchboxes and the lids in their variations. and combine them in bundles.

Comment: That would certainly make it easier to maintain, but I'm also interested if there is something like the checkbox method I described. So I can keep my 5 products as they are and add some attribute to them without creating a separate product.

Comment: so you want a checkbox for each lid color ??

Comment: Since I figured it would be very hard to maintain all box/lid combinations I was wondering if I could add a checkbox to `make the lid the same color as the box`. So I can stick to my 5 boxes as they are, I do not have to create separate lid products, and on the box I add this one checkbox that will make the box 1 euro more expensive for the color. I guess this will be the easiest way, but I don't know if it is possible.